# How to fix "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous." error in Holt's Exponential Smoothing

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, statsmodels

I am using Holt's method for Exponential Smoothing from the python package statsmodels.  I am trying to create forecasts for some time series data.  I am able to create 2 out of the 3 forecasts.  When I try to use an exponential model rather than a Holt's additive model I get an error.

I am using python 3.6.8 and statsmodels 0.9.0.

This works:

```
fit1 = Holt(df1).fit(smoothing_level=0.8, smoothing_slope=0.2, optimized=False)
fcast1 = fit1.forecast(12).rename("Holt's linear trend")
```

This does not work:

```
fit2 = Holt(df1, exponential=True).fit(smoothing_level=0.8, smoothing_slope=0.2, optimized=False)
fcast2 = fit2.forecast(12).rename("Exponential trend")
```

I get the error:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Comment: You may wish to include full traceback for your error, since the error you have is very common.

Comment: My guess is you were passing a `DataFrame` rather than a `Series` to `Holt` model, which would cause problem when `exponential=True`. Try `fit2 = Holt(df1.iloc[:,0], exponential=True).fit(smoothing_level=0.8, smoothing_slope=0.2, optimized=False)`.

Comment: @Ian, thank you very much that solved it! Thank you!